Turning an apple into a blackhole: feasibility & effects on surroundings
I read that it is possible to turn an apple into a blackhole by compressing it to the size of 10^-28m, according to the Schwarzschild radius formula.
My first question concerns the feasibility of that compression. Would it be possible to compress that much, how much energy would it take, and would it refuse to compress itself due to some repulsing forces?
The second one is, if we assume it's feasible, what would happen when you let go of that apple, say put it on top of a table. Would it suck the whole earth?

Black hole evaporation time scale would be on the order of $10^{-20}$ seconds (I think). That probably wouldn't even be noticeable.

@KyleKanos Make sure you can do something with the resulting super-Tsar Bomba-level explosion, though. Mass-energy conservation is real.

Your question is based on a widespread misconception that the Schwarzschild radius is the radius of a black hole. It isn’t. The so-called “Schwarzschild radius” is the circumference of the horizon divided by $2\pi$. The actual spatial radius of any black hole (in our coordinates) is zero. Also, black holes don’t evaporate. The “Hawking radiation” has not been predicted by a confirmed theory, has not been observed, and, if existed, would violate major laws of physics (Information Paradox). This “radiation” is just an artifact of forcing together two incompatible theories, classical and quantum.

@safesphere I agree with your comment but it would be bad practice to say that “black holes don’t evaporate” as a statement. The correct-ish answer is that we don’t know because we’ve never observed them and we don’t have an adequate theory of quantum gravity to work with. The information paradox is real, but we’ve also observed black holes to exist directly… the safest answer is that we don’t know yet.

@controlgroup Agreed, but the misbalance of the opinions is not on my side. Everyone out there states that black holes do evaporate while I am the only one who says that they don’t. So when everyone else starts following your suggestion, then I will too :) The Hawking radiation has not been predicted by a confirmed theory or observed and contradicts foundational laws of nature. Plus it is practically unfalsifiable. Thus, if I can claim that “black holes don’t emit magical unicorns”, then in the same scientific sense I  also can claim that “black holes don’t emit the Hawking radiation”.

That’s probably more scientifically-minded of you than most professional scientists… Fundamentally I agree on the difficulty of falsification, and on the info paradox, but it’s not like BHs don’t also cause other things to go bad in interesting ways. I personally learn and work with Hawking-rad theories just in case they or something like them turns out to be the case in quantum gravity, whenever that gets discovered, and if it doesn’t turn out to happen, then my math just got a lot simpler ;)

@controlgroup Agreed again, a good approach. The quantum realm is weird and full of surprises.  It is quite evident that black holes are inherently quantum objects, so the lack of quantum gravity is a shame. And the reason it’s lacking is not the complexity. Fundamental principles are always simple. The reason is wrong initial assumptions on what quantum gravity should be, so everyone just looks in the wrong direction from the start IMHO.

$10^{-28}\,\mathrm{m}$ is near the Planck scale. That’s much smaller than a proton; given that compressing it that much would require overcoming electron and neutron degeneracy pressure, this cannot be accomplished with human technology; if you tried it with an alien’s advanced supercompressor, you would still find that the supercompressor (made of atoms) can’t well compress the apple (also made of atoms) to something many orders of magnitude smaller than an atom. Not only that, but even if you did somehow manage it, the Compton wavelength and de Broglie wavelength of the resulting object would be much larger than the Schwarzschild radius and it wouldn’t really be a black hole (at least, not in the non-quantum gravitational sense).
Black holes also decay at a rate inversely proportional to the cube of their mass. An apple has extremely little mass and an apple-massed black hole will (unless micro black holes are stable somehow) release all its mass-energy in Hawking radiation practically immediately. Simple Fermi-style estimation: the speed of light squared is roughly $c^2=10^{17}$, the mass of the apple is roughly $m=10^{-1}$, the mass-energy contained is roughly $mc^2=10^{16}$, and in kilotons of TNT (dividing by roughly $5\cdot10^{12}$) we see that the resulting explosion from the apple black hole will release a total energy of around 500 megatons of TNT.
You might also ask why it would be able to suck up anything at all. It’s a tiny fraction of an atom’s radius; how would you expect it to “consume” an atom, or even an electron?

thanks for all your help and answers. I asked a follow up question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/831030/what-would-the-cinematic-of-a-black-hole-falling-on-an-object-look-like

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
