What would the kinematic of a black hole falling on an object look like?
I wonder what would the kinematics of a black hole falling on an object be.
To make it realistic, I got told that the black hole needs to have a radius bigger than atoms, so that it can swallow them. I think atoms have a radius of $10^{-10}m$, so let's make a BH with a radius of $10^{-9}m$ which if I'm not mistaken gives it a mass of $10^{18}kg$ which is still far lighter than the earth ($10^{24}kg$).
Since the BH is lighter than the earth, from a stationary observer, it's the BH that we see falling towards the earth. At long range, my understanding is that the BH looks just like a normal object falling. But how does it behave as it gets closer ? Does it end up touching the ground, and piercing through it and going to the core, or something else?

These guys have researched this and animated it https://youtu.be/8nHBGFKLHZQ


Ignore the fact that the BH can swallow atoms. It probably won’t do so very quickly (from both the spacing between atoms and time dilation effects as it moves quickly through space after reaching the Earth). Think about it like this: a high-speed nanometer-sized black hole would create extreme time dilation for those atoms that it’s about to “hit”, such that atoms being pulled in from space adjacent to the BH’s path don’t end up actually within it, so the total volume “consumed” would just be a 1 nm-by-~6500 km column, which will not have significant mass.

Ignore the physical matter of the Earth completely. The BH’s mass is so much higher than that of an atom that hitting an atom (or a quadrillion atoms) elastically or inelastically is not really going to affect it’s momentum substantially. Its momentum will be proportional to its mass, which is a mind-boggling $10^{18}$-ish kilograms, compared to around $10^{-27}$ kilograms for hydrogen atoms. Hitting an atom of hydrogen (at rest) could thus reduce its momentum by a factor of at most $1-\frac{10^{-27}}{10^{18}}=1-10^{-45}\approx1$.


The BH will pass through the Earth, not slowing down substantially, and then fly out the other side. If it was launched with negative total mechanical energy (i.e. within Earth’s gravity well), it will remain in orbit. If it was launched with positive or zero total mechanical energy (i.e. outside Earth’s gravity well), it will fly off towards infinity.
What you have left is an idealized mass moving in an idealized gravity well, perhaps one best described by a twofold interior/exterior Schwarzschild/Lense-Thirring metric (or just Newtonian gravity if you don’t care about perfect accuracy). The kinematics will be described by basic orbital mechanics: the black hole’s total mechanical energy will remain constant (barring very minor changes to its mass as it absorbs, which will be very little on each pass). If you somehow keep it from evaporating (and thus destroying the planet in a supernova-like explosion), it would, eventually, consume the entire planet through this process. It would take longer than the Earth has to live due to a dying Sun is my bet, but without information on the tightness of its orbit I can’t fact-check that.

I didn't really understand the part with the gravity well and mechanical energy. Given that the black hole is only accelerated due to falling, if it pierces through the earth, as soon as it has gone beyond the core, won't it start being slowed down ? If I jump to a hole on the earth from one side to the other (not considering temperature/pression issues), won't I start accelerating until the core, then start decelerating, and reach the other side at 0m/s, and unless someone catches me, go back again towards the hole, in a never ending loop (if there's no resistance)?

Like I said in the answer, you can functionally ignore the matter of the Earth. And yes, the whole hole-in-the-earth thing is correct: the path you follow is an orbit, which the BH will follow as well. Mechanical energy just describes how much potential/kinetic energy the BH has; if it’s positive, it has enough to escape Earth’s gravity, and if negative, it will forever be trapped in Earth’s gravity well barring an energy change of some sort.

To me an orbit is a ellipse or circle whereas this is a line. So what you're saying is that the BH would end up going up and down through the earth endlessly, whilst not being affected by the matter it goes through ? I'm only vaguely familiar with the concept of potential / kinetic energy, so I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking whether the BH has a initial velocity ? If so the answer is no, it's just moving due to falling, as though it just appeared out of nowhere and was put there.

An orbit can be any ellipse with the gravitating body at one focus, or in a special case of being allowed to fall into a gravitating body (where at the center the gravitational force goes to zero) it can be a straight line back and forth. If the BH starts at rest, then it will always have negative mechanical energy at any distance from the Earth and will thus always end up in one such orbit.

your answer is clear then, thanks.

just one follow up question, and then I'm done for the day: how then are we to know that there isn't a blackhole doing just that right now ?

actually just one more please, can you please do the math of how long it would take to consume the planet, if it starts with 0 velocity and at ground level (as in, somehow created by humans) ?

That math is extremely complex. Any answer would be an approximation. I doubt that anything short of numerical integration of variables (which would take an extremely long time even with a supercomputer) would get anywhere close to the correct answer.

well i would certainly welcome an approximation, with added assumptions if they are required to facilitate the math, but if it still says too difficult, I understand. At one point some people were afraid that the LHC could create BHs, so I thought this kind of calculus would have already been done. What about the other question, how are we to know that there isn't a tiny blackhole going back and forth on earth right now ?

The LHC cannot create micro black holes, so the math was never done. Its maximum energy (~14 TeV) is not nearly high enough to produce micro black holes. The people who were afraid were not working there nor were they particle physicists or relativists. And whether or not micro black holes do exist at all (and might be going through the Earth/through space/etc) is an open question in astrophysics. They have been proposed as dark matter candidates.

@elilu The luminosity of your nanometre BH has a luminosity of ~0.78 milliwatts, but its temperature is >182000 K, which makes it hard to absorb matter. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

so one could be going back and forth through earth right now, and we wouldn't know about it ?

Sure, to the extent that something that doesn't really affect anything can be going anywhere at any time without us knowing about it.

By the way, I just did a super-simple absolute-lower-limit estimation (assuming the BH sweeps a volume equal to its EH surface area times the Earth's diameter once a second) and found that it has to take at least 859945966514459640000 millennia to consume the entire Earth. I am not concerned.

Cool, thanks for doing the math! @PM2Ring, why is the temperature related to the difficulty of absorbing matter ?

@elilu If black holes actually radiated, this radiation would repel the infalling matter by making it hot like jets of rocket engines.
